# PHP mkdir creates bad / corrupt directories?

Tags: php, ftp, directory, mkdir, winscp

I have an image uploader, for which the directory should be dynamic based on a variable. Everything works on it's own except creating the directory. The directory appears in WinSCP and the php code echo's that the image has been uploaded there however when trying to get into the directory I get an error:

```
Error changing directory to'foobar'.
   Can't change directory to foobar: No such file or directory.
```

Below is the only relevant code to this issue (I think).

```
$target_dir = "../images/ " . $model_name . "/";
if (!file_exists("$target_dir")) {
mkdir("$target_dir", 0777, true);
}
```

I should be able to log onto linux and rmdir -Rf from terminal to get rid of this directory however I would like to know what is causing this and if there is a fix.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Please explain "when trying to get into the directory" how you try to get into it? using your FTP client of php code?

Comment: When navigating the web-server using WinSCP as an FTP protocol.

Comment: Are you able to view the directory content through the browser? for example can you view the images e.g. www.yoursite.com/images/foo/image1.png

Comment: What I'm suspecting is permission error. Your php script has a different privilege than your FTP user. Since you created the dir using the script, then the APACHE user (which what you said you only get rid of it if you access through the terminal) only can remove it. 
In WinSCP I think you can see the user/groups type and permission given next to the directory.

Comment: Please include piece of WinSCP log showing (parent) directory listing and the attempt to enter the directory.